# how to display specific words per page

Tags: string, split, words

hey guys,
i have a string which contains say 100 words, now i want to split that string for words and want to display 10 words per page. how this could be done... i am not getting the logic for the same..

please reply with how this could be resolved.

Comment: What programming language are you doing this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the words are seperated by white spaces,count for it and make arrays containing 10 words each. if words are separated, split(java) or explode(php) to arrays and combine 10 to make a new array n display it in each page

Comment: can you please elaborate it more, i am not getting through the logic

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about php, you can do something like this :

```
<?php
$words = explode(' ', $string,); // create an array with each word as items.
$start = 0; // index of the first word
$number = 10; // number of words per page
$words_part = array_slice($words, $start, $number); // take 10 words from the array, starting at $start

foreach($words_part as $word) {
   echo $word;
}
?>
```

Basically, we separate each words using a space as separator, then we take the relevant part of the resulting array (the ten first words).

You can easily the number of words taken in each part by modifying the `$number` variable, or the start place with the `$start` variable.

Implementation in another language will be identical.

I hope this help.

Comment: can you please help me for asp.net, i am a dumb for php